# Query failed only on IE browser

Tags: php, sql-server, apache, request

My goal is to move an PHP application from a Windows Server 2000 - SQL Server 2005 - Apache 2.2 to a new a server with Windows Server 2012 - SQL Server 2012 - Apache 2.2.

On the new server I've installed and configured SQL Server 2012 - Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.2.9.

I copied the application and the database on the new server.

Unfortunately the application didn't work with Internet Explorer. I cannot access to my application account because it failed on the login form. It works with Firefox and Chrome.

I can read on the Apache log : PHP Warning:  mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: message: Incorrect syntax near '='. (severity 15)

I tried the application under PHP 5.4 and Apache 2.4 using the ODBC library for handling requests. I meet again the same error with Internet Explorer.

On the old server the application work fine with IE7-8-9-10.

Somebody can help me ?

Regards

Comment: PHP runs on the server side - it doesn't care what browser you're using. The issue will be with how you're calling it, but given that you've given no code, it's hard to say; I'd guess that you're using JQuery to do the login, and that some of the functions aren't supported in IE.

Comment: What happens in the browser when you try to log in? Is an error thrown? Or did the log in just failed? Or were you silently signed out?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using JQuery, data from login form are passed to $_POST to another page.
The log just failed it didn't recognize me.

Here is the form

```
<fieldset class="fld_type" style="width:80%;">
<legend class="lgd_style">Connexion - Inscription</legend>
<table align="center">
<?php if(!empty($erreur)){ ?>
<tr>
<td align="right" colspan="3" style="color:red; font-size:14px;" ><?php echo $erreur; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?> 
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="4"><img style="height:90px;" src="images/connect.png" alt="Authentification" /></td>
<td class="right"><b>N&ordm; Pan&eacute;liste (identifiant):</b></td>
<td><input style="border:1px solid #0075bc;" onFocus="modif_champs(this);" onBlur="default_champs(this);" type="text" id="txt_login" name="txt_login" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="right"><b>Mot de passe :</b></td>
<td><input style="border:1px solid #0075bc;" onFocus="modif_champs(this);" onBlur="default_champs(this);" type="password" id="txt_mdp" name="txt_mdp" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><a class="strong" href="#MDPOublie" onClick="$('formMDPOublie').appear();Effect.ScrollTo('MDPOublie'); return false;" >Mot de passe oublié ?</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>
<!--<input onClick="verifLoginMDP(this.form);" type="button" value="Se connecter" id="btn_valider" name="btn_valider" class="btn_style" />-->
<input type="submit" value="Se connecter" id="btn_valider" name="btn_valider" class="btn_style" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="3"><hr style="color:white;" /></td></tr>
</table>
<table align="center">
<tr>
<td align="right"><a href="questionnaire_consommation/form_inscriptionPaneliste.php"><img style="height:40px; width:40px; " src="images/addP2.png" alt="Nouveau ?" /></a></td>
<td><a class="strong" href="questionnaire_consommation/form_inscriptionPaneliste.php">Vous n'&ecirc;tes pas encore inscrit ?</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</fieldset>
```

Here is the php code that handle the login

```
if(isset($_POST['txt_login']) AND isset($_POST['txt_mdp'])){
    $login = Securite::bdd($_POST['txt_login']);
    $mdp = md5($_POST['txt_mdp']); // cryptage du mot de passe
    $erreur = "";

    /* Verification de l'utilisateur
     *********************************/      
    $requeteVerif = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM paneliste WHERE PANELISTE_LOGIN = '" . $login . "' AND PANELISTE_MDP = '" . $mdp . "'";
    $stmtVerif = ExecRequete($requeteVerif, Connexion());
    $donneesVerif = ObjetSuivant($stmtVerif);

    if($donneesVerif[0] == 0){
    //Le paneliste n'est pas referencé dans la base de données
        $erreur = "Les identifiants de connexion sont incorrects !";
    }else{  
        $requeteIDPaneliste = "SELECT PANELISTE_ID, PANELISTE_TYPE, PANELISTE_DATENAISS, SITE_ID FROM paneliste WHERE PANELISTE_LOGIN = '" . $login . "' AND PANELISTE_MDP = '" . $mdp . "'";
        $stmtIDPaneliste = ExecRequete($requeteIDPaneliste, Connexion());
        $IDPaneliste = ObjetSuivant($stmtIDPaneliste);
        $_SESSION['id_paneliste'] = $IDPaneliste[0];
        $_SESSION['site_id'] = $IDPaneliste[3];
        $_SESSION['type_user'] =  $IDPaneliste[1];
        $_SESSION['type_questionnaire'] = getTypeQuestionnaire($IDPaneliste[2]);

        // Correction de l'erreur #90 : Des références au site de Vandoeuvre (e-mail et téléphone) apparaissent quelque soit le site de rattachement du panéliste.
        // A la connexion, on enregistre donc ces valeurs en session.
        $siteInfo = recupererSiteInfo($_SESSION['id_paneliste']);
        $_SESSION['site_admin_nom'] = $siteInfo['SITE_ADMIN_NOM'];
        $_SESSION['site_admin_prenom'] = $siteInfo['SITE_ADMIN_PRENOM'];
        $_SESSION['site_tel'] = $siteInfo['SITE_TEL'];
        $_SESSION['site_email'] = $siteInfo['SITE_EMAIL'];
        $_SESSION['site_horaires'] = $siteInfo['SITE_HORAIRES'];

        // Correction de l'erreur #132 : Certains panélistes ne peuvent accéder au site, car la variable de session est effacée après une redirection par header().
        session_write_close();

        header("Location: /partie_paneliste/accueil_paneliste.php");    
    }
}

    afficheEnTete("Espace de Connexion", "");
```

Here is the php code that execute query

```
// Execution d'une requête SQL
function ExecRequete($requete, $connexion){

    $resultat = mssql_query($requete, $connexion);

    if($resultat){
        return $resultat;
    }
    else{
        echo "<b>Erreur dans l'execution de la requete '$requete' .</b>";
        exit;
    }
} // Fin de la fonction ExecRequete

//Recherche de l'objet suivant
function ObjetSuivant($resultat){
    return mssql_fetch_array($resultat);
}

//Recherche de la ligne suivante (retourne un tableau)
function LigneSuivante($resultat){
    return mssql_fetch_assoc($resultat);
}

// Correction de l'erreur #187 : Erreur SQL lors de la mise à jour des fréquences de consommation.
// Nombre d'enregistrements trouvés
function Nombre($resultat){
    return mssql_num_rows($resultat);
}

?>
```

It fails on line `$resultat = mssql_query($requete, $connexion);`